# spring3 @autowired and @inject

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

i'm spring2.5, i normally use @autowired for DI.  If i not wrong, in spring3, we can use @Inject for similar feature right?  please comment.  I tried to add @Inject instead of @autowired but doesnt work. need extra library?

Comment: define "didn't work". What happened?

Comment: You can also use @Resource instead for DI

Comment: I'm really impressed how, after 351 questions, you still haven't learned that "it doesn't work" is _not_ sufficient information.

Comment: @Bozho, will write in detail next time. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "doesn't work" you mean that the annotation can't be resolved, then yes, you need a JSR-330 API library. You can download it [here](http://code.google.com/p/atinject/).

Or if you use maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```